# Can AVPlayerItem load a time range before seeking to it?

Tags: ios, video, avplayer, avplayeritem

I have a requirement for a fast seek with AVPlayer playing HLS video. The standard seekToTime methods on AVPlayerItem work fine, but have a noticeable lag when seeking unless the video at the seek point is already loaded - as you would expect.

Is it possible to preload the video at a specific time range before seeking, so that the subsequent seek is faster? For this use case, the specific seek points are known in advance, and the relevant piece of video at the seek point is ~10 seconds.

Currently this feature is implemented by chopping each piece of video at the seek points into its own MP4 file and using AVQueuePlayer to get continuous playback between each piece. But this is not ideal for several reasons, and we are looking at ways of using the single large video file with improved seek handling.

I've read through all the AVPlayer/AVPlayerItem API documentation and can't see a way to do this.

Any ideas? Perhaps this requires using something other than AVPlayer?

iOS8+